# Bitset. Изменение битов элементов

Tags: c++

Есть некоторые массивы

```
bitset<8> BIN_BROADCAST[4] = {}; // пустой
bitset<8> BIN_REZ[4] = {}; // тут {10000010 00000100 01100100 00000000}
```

Нужно заменить последние 10 нулей на 1.
Пробовал несколько вариантов реализации, но ничего разумного не вышло, вот моё последнее решение(мне оно кажется наиболее логичным), но оно вызывает в билдере `external exception eefface`

```
bitset<8> BIN_HOST[1] = {}; // кол-во нулей для замены
int KOL_NULL = 0;


for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 8; j > 0; j--){

       BIN_BROADCAST[i][j] = BIN_REZ[i][j].flip();
       KOL_NULL += 1;

       if(KOL_NULL == BIN_HOST[0].to_ulong()){
            break;
       }
    }

    break;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Memo1 ->Lines ->Add(BIN_BROADCAST[i].to_ulong());
}
```

Comment: Вообше ничего не понятно, но могу напомнить, что  bitset имеет достаточно функциональностей для того, чтобы не писать цикл для инвертирования битовых значений.

Comment: @ AR Hovsepyan, да все верно, имеет достаточно, но что бы инвертировать  определенный набор битов по мойму никак без цикла. Да и что собственно не понятно!?

Comment: непонятно какие последные 10 нулей? Последные в массиве?  Если да, то  установить все биты в 1 в последном битсет `BIN_REZ[3].set()`  и  первые два предпоследнего `BIN_REZ[2].set(0, 2)`, Вот эти два оператор решают всю вашу задачу. Нет, не нужен цикл при работе с битсет, если знать все его методы и правильно использовать

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, дело в том что в зависимости от введенных значений, количество заменяемых нулей меняется и может понадобиться заменить не 10 нулей, а скажем 12 или всего 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично мое мнение в данной задаче не хранить все в массиве, а в bitset<32>.

Чтобы поменять бито с позиции a по позицию б самое элементарное пройтись циклом и дернуть там флип.

Вот минимальный пример кода.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <bitset>


void FormOut(std::bitset<32> bs) {
    for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::bitset<8> tmp;
        for (std::size_t j{ 0 }; j < 8; ++j) {
            tmp[j] = bs[4 * i + j];
        }
        std::cout << tmp.to_ulong() << " ";

    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main() {

    const std::size_t bit_size{32};
    std::bitset<bit_size> bs;

    FormOut(bs);

    for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < bit_size; ++i) {
        bs[i] = 1;
    }

    FormOut(bs);

    std::size_t from{3}, to {12};
    if (from > bit_size || to > bit_size) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (to < from) {
        std::swap(to, from);
    }

    for (std::size_t i{from}; i < to; ++i) {
        bs[i].flip();
    }

    FormOut(bs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ,Вопрос не связан с примером вашего кода. Почему при попытке осуществить такое  `BIN_REZ[i][j].set()` выходит ошибка `'set' is not a member of 'bitset<8>::reference'`. В то время как `BIN_REZ[i][j].flip()` работает без ошибок

Comment: @КонстантинКлименко попробуйте написать BIN_REZ[i].set(j, true)

Answer (score 0):

как минимум, вместо

```
for(int i = 4; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 8; j > 0; j--){
```

надо

```
for(int i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
    for(int j = 7; j >= 0; j--){
```

а по-хорошему, надо переделать вообще всё. Массивы из битмапов какие-то на ровном месте...

Comment: чем Вам bitset не нравиться?